# How can I create a photo slider on iPhone Safari with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile-safari, jqtouch

I'd like to create an product image viewer for an iPhone version of an ecommerce site, and have it behave something like the Photos app.

Ideally, you would be able to slide images to move back and forth in the product image gallery.

This will all be done in mobile Safari.

I did a little experimenting with jqTouch, but its doesn't look like it would support this idea (it has swipe support, but there's no apparent way to link sliding to dragging an image).

Any plugin or implementation ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you're building specifically for the iPhone, you may want to look into CSS animations instead. You get hardware acceleration in that case and thus the best performance.

Comment: Have you found a solution, Ben? Remember that it's perfectly okay to answers your own questions here on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 2):

i needed the same, solution was to use [cycle](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cycle) and swipe plugins:

"#gallery" is a container with all img tags in it.

```
$(function() {
 $('#gallery').cycle({
  fx: 'scrollHorz',
  timeout: 0,
  next: '',
  prev: '',
  speed: 300,
  nowrap: 0
 });
});
$(function() {
 $('#gallery').swipe({
  swipeLeft: function() { $('#gallery').cycle("next"); },
  swipeRight: function() { $('#gallery').cycle("prev") },
  threshold: {
   x: 15,
   y: 99999
  },
  preventDefaultEvents: false
 });
});
```

it works, but not exactly like Photo library, because images doesnt drag to 50% of width before changing. just like in crmunro's solution, but based on jQuery and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you've solved this, but an iWebkit a user has created http://worldofsai.com/photos_flick.html - maybe you could base it on that?

Comment: Original code for that gallery and the tutorial available: http://mydailyphoto.com/blog/iphone-safari-flick-navigation

Answer (score 0):

you can check [this](http://tlrobinson.net/iphone/lighttable/) example. open it in safari on your iPhone))) you can rotate, move and scale images

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like to use jQuery, and I don't need anywhere near that kind of flexbility. I'd just like the images to slide left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Qtouch received a significant update in july.
The full source package now include demos for video embedding and swipeable image galleries.

You can find the download of r148 at this url:
http://code.google.com/p/jqextensions/downloads/list

It works very well.